# Datagridview edit in new form

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, datagridview

When I double clicked on DataGridView cell (row) I need to select and edit this row in a new form. What I've done so far is:

```
public partial class Vozila : Form
{
    
    public static int cellValue = 0;

    public Vozila()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }       
    
    private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        cellValue = Convert.ToInt32(((DataGridView)sender).SelectedCells[0].Value);
        DodajVozilo check = new DodajVozilo();
        Check.Show();
    }  
}
```

Idea to do that is to use variable cellValue (in new form DodajVozilo on DodajVozilo_Load) and with MySql SELECT command with clause
`WHERE id=cellValue` but a can't get any usable result. What is WHERE clause syntax with public static int variable?
Any other idea?

Comment: From reading your question I think you are looking for the where clause of your SQL Query is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

you describe a new variable in DodajVozilo for example public int id;

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
       {
            cellValue = Convert.ToInt32(((DataGridView)sender).SelectedCells[0].Value);
            DodajVozilo check = new DodajVozilo();
       check.id=cellValue;
            check.Show();
        }
```

after You should query with id in  MYSQL.

Comment: The same problem again. Can't query anything.

Comment: The same problem again. Can't query anything.

Comment: I want to see DodajVozilo_Load. method. Can you show me code?